# Add an email to user's address book using javascript/html

Tags: javascript, mailto, email-client

Is there a way to use javascript/html to add an email address to visitors address book?

I'm looking for a function similar to "mailto" anchor, which opens users email client and opens a new message tab, only instead of opening the mail client with new message, i would like to open it and go to "add contacts" tab

I've read something about javascript Intent's but those are currently unsupported by most browsers and as far as i know, don't allow adding contacts.

Comment: No, there is no general-purpose JS solution for this – especially not considering the multitude of possible “mail clients”.

Comment: give up while you're still ahead

Comment: I guess you could try to generate a [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) with the info, then let them download it... but no, there is no "mailto"-ish function to do this.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to use a vCard.  Something like [this][1], or [this][2] to download a vCard and maybe the device supports it, maybe it doesn't.  It should work on iOS at least.


  [1]: https://github.com/nilclass/vcardjs
  [2]: https://github.com/jasperla/node-vcard

Comment: The client opted for vCard option, so @pennstatephil post your comment in the form of an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, there is no function like "mailto" to create contacts-- the closest you can get is to create a [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) and have the user download and open it.